# FOSUserBundle How to normalize UserName at login?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FOSUB with Symfony 3.2
I wish to "normalize" the username when the user logs in.
By "normalize", I mean I have a "NormalizeService" to be called **before** checking in DB if user exist.
The process would be :

```
$normalizedUsername = $NormalizeService->normalize($providedUsername);
logUser($normalizedUsername, $providedPassword); // this is a simple login as usual
```

What do you think is the best way to do this ? Create a [custom UserProvider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) ? I'm not sure it's what I need.

Regards

Comment: Basically you want use your own canonicalizer? http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/canonicalizer.html

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I need. Maybe you can create an "Answer" so I can accept it and make it visible ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: okay @Jeremie, done

Comment: Thanks a lot @Federkun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/canonicalizer.html) of FOSUserBundle says:

> FOSUserBundle stores canonicalized versions of the username and the email which are used when querying and checking for uniqueness.

You just need to create a class that implements [CanonicalizerInterface](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Util/CanonicalizerInterface.php)

```
namespace AppBundle\Util;

use FOS\UserBundle\Util\CanonicalizerInterface;

class MyCanonicalizer implements CanonicalizerInterface
{
    private $normalizeService;

    public function __construct(NormalizeService $normalizeService)
    {
        $this->normalizeService = $normalizeService;
    }

    public function canonicalize($string)
    {
        if (null === $string) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->normalizeService->normalize($string);
    }
}
```

register it as a service:

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.my_canonicalizer:
        class: AppBundle\Util\MyCanonicalizer
        arguments: ['@normalize_service'] # your NormalizeService 
        public: false
```

and then configure FOSUserBundle to use it:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_user:
    service:
        email_canonicalizer:    app.my_canonicalizer
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PRE_SUBMIT FormEvent in which you normalize the username.

See [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html#submitting-a-form-formevents-pre-submit-formevents-submit-and-formevents-post-submit) for more information.

Comment: I'm not sure how to bind this to FOS login form ?

Comment: You can create your own UserBundle and override some of FOS's functionalities. Take a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html)

Comment: What Controller is it about ? `SecurityController.php` ?

Comment: Actually I think @federkun's answer is what you are looking for

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for your help.